# Addin Outlook disabled after open .msg

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an issue with my Addin Outlook.

When I open a .msg

If Outlook was opened no problem.
If Outlook was closed my Addin is not loaded like McAfee's Outlook Addin.
But when I close the .msg and open Outlook, McAfee is loaded but my Addin is not loaded.

Do you have some idea how I could always load my addin or by default loaded when I open Outlook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many reasons why your add-in is not loaded...

Is your add-in listed in the Disabled COM add-ins list?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Also you may find the [Troubleshooting COM Add-In load failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures/) article helpful.